# create collection index from firestore trigger automatically

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am wondering if there is a way to write cloud function or some other way to create a composite index based on a trigger. I see there is option from console to create but I want to be able to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

The Firestore API has an [endpoint](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.collectionGroups.indexes/create) meant to create indexes, so it is possible to programmatically create composite indexes. Upon that fact you may put the code in a Cloud Function and trigger it as you see convenient.

The code below may be used to that effect. You'll notice that instead of issuing the call directly to the REST endpoint I'm using the [api-discovery](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) library, which allows to create HTTP clients for most GCP provided API's.

```py
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

# The steps below create a credentials object from a service account key.
# This allows to authenticate the calls to the Firestore API
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    './key.json')

scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(
    ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])


# Instantiate the Firestore API client
service = build('firestore', 'v1', credentials=scoped_credentials)

# Variables used to perform the call. Replace them as needed.
project = "PROJECT_ID"
collection = "COLLECTION_NAME"

parent = "projects/{}/databases/(default)/collectionGroups/{}".format(project, collection)

# The body of the request as specified in the API docs
# The example below creates a composite index for the fields votes and name
body = {
    "queryScope": "COLLECTION",
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldPath": "votes",
            "order": "DESCENDING"
        },
        {
            "fieldPath": "name",
            "order": "DESCENDING"
        },
    ]
}

# Make the API call
res = service.projects().databases().collectionGroups().indexes().create(parent=parent, body=body).execute()


print(res)
```

That said, I would not recommend to create indexes on-the-fly unless absolutely required. Indexes are billed and take time to create, it's usually more convenient to perform separate queries and merge the results in the application code. Furthermore if you use the `firestore.indexes.json` file, any index created this way won't be saved, and they'll be lost the next time you issue a `firebase deploy` command.